# how to import multiple files on remix IDE using github url?

Tags: solidity, remix, import

**i'm using the following way! but got error URL not parseable: Ownable.sol!!**

```
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
```

Answer (score 3):

You URL should start with 'http://' or 'https://' otherwise it's just a path. Also, OpenZeppelin renamed the repo 'zeppelin-solidity' to 'openzeppelin-solidity' a while ago.

Try this:

`import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";`

**-- update--**

Be sure to check out the structure of [the openzeppelin-solidity github repository](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts). The `StandardToken` contract has also been moved and was renamed to `ERC20`.

Instead of

```
import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol"; 
import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol";
```

use

```
import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol"; 
import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
```

Comment: hello! @henk ! it works fine but when i import 2 urls then it gave error=> **Unable to import "undefined": Not Found**  i'm using `import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
import "http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol";`

Comment: Updated my answer. Be sure to check out the structure of [the openzeppelin-solidity github repository](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts)

Comment: Thanks!! @Henk! but problem remains the same!!

Comment: It's working perfectly in Remix. What editor are you using? Does it have an internet connection?

Comment: it shows me error undefined!! else everything works fine!! @Henk